# Roslyn Rewrite Method Calls to use await Modifier

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I a bunch of C# Files that I want to migrate to a new version of an internal framework we use for development. So far I have been able to accomplish certain things But there is a particular method invocation that i have to modify to use await modifier and the method calls come  in different flavors like so

```
 var a = EntityService.GetBy(Entities.INSTANT_ISSUANCE_REQUEST, requestFilter);
 var b = EntityService.GetBy(Entities.ISSUANCE_SETTINGS, new DejaVuObject()).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have to modify the above method calls so that they use the following syntax

```
 var a = await EntityService.GetBy(Entities.INSTANT_ISSUANCE_REQUEST, requestFilter);
 var b = await EntityService.GetBy(Entities.ISSUANCE_SETTINGS, new DejaVuObject()).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am using Roslyn CSharpSyntaxWriter to traverse the syntax tree.

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitLocalDeclarationStatement(LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax node)
{
    var variableDeclarations = 
        from i in node.DescendantNodes().OfType<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>()
        where i.DescendantNodes().OfType<EqualsValueClauseSyntax>().Any<EqualsValueClauseSyntax>(
            p => p.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().Any<InvocationExpressionSyntax>())
        select i;

    foreach (var syntax in variableDeclarations)
    {
        var equalsToken = syntax.DescendantNodes();
        //now we have the equals token 
        foreach (var syntaxNode in equalsToken)
        {
            if (syntaxNode is EqualsValueClauseSyntax)
            {
                var equalsValueSyntax = syntaxNode.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
                foreach (var invocationExpressionSyntax in equalsValueSyntax)
                {
                    var simpleMemberAcessExpressions = invocationExpressionSyntax
                        .DescendantNodes()
                        .OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>()
                        .Where(i => i.Identifier.Text == "EntityService");
                    foreach (var simpleMemberAcessExpression in simpleMemberAcessExpressions)
                    {
                        var newExpression = $"{invocationExpressionSyntax.ToFullString()}";
                        Console.WriteLine(newExpression);
                        //TODO: Modify the Node
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return base.VisitLocalDeclarationStatement(node);
}
```

My problem here is the output in Console is somewhat duplicative

```
EntityService.GetBy(Entities.ISSUANCE_SETTINGS, new DejaVuObject()).FirstOrDefault();
EntityService.GetBy(Entities.ISSUANCE_SETTINGS, new DejaVuObject())
```

Both refer to same `InvocationExpression` but because of the `FirstOrDefault()` it shows up twice in the console output

I would like for a way to filter the results so that they contain only unique Method Invocations and perform the actual modification of the method call by adding the await modifier and updating the node.

Comment: For that to actually work you'd need a custom extension method that handles FirstOrDefault for `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`, e.g. `public static Task<T> FirstOrDefault<T>(this Task<IEnumerable<T>> e) => (await e).FirstOrDefault();`, otherwise you need to rewrite your second statement as `(await EntityService.GetBy(Entities.ISSUANCE_SETTINGS, new DejaVuObject())).FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, why override `VisitLocalDeclarationStatement`? Looks like you should be overriding `VisitInvocationExpression`.

You shouldn't be doing this:

```
var simpleMemberAcessExpressions = 
    invocationExpressionSyntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>()
```

Instead, it should be something like:

```
var identifier = 
    (node.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)?.Expression as IdentifierNameSyntax;

if (identifier != null && identifier.Identifier.Text == "EntityService")
{
    // process the invocation expression
}
```

Assuming the invocation expression is called `node`, your new expression is probably

```
var newExpression = 
    SyntaxFactory.ParenthesizedExpression(SyntaxFactory.AwaitExpression(node))
    .WithAdditionalAnnotations(Simplifier.Annotation)
    .WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation);
```